# Already an open DataReader associated with this Connection

Tags: c#, mysql

I use the code below to get data from mySql in C#. When I do that I get the error mentioned below the code. I found some question about the subject but they used `DataReader`, and I'm not.

```
MySqlConnection sq = new MySqlConnection("...");
sq.Open();
MySqlCommand sc = new MySqlCommand("select * from users", sq);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sc);
da.Fill(ds);
sq.Close();
```

My Error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection
>   which must be closed first.

Answer (score 1):

in your connection string just add **"MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"**

Comment: I think mysql doesn't support this

Comment: Oh!! i missed that, i think you should try USING keyword which will dispose connections after use

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this fixes your issue, however...

Use the `using` statament for your connection, the command and the dataadapter. This disposes all objects that implement `IDisposable` and also closes the connection:

```
using(var sq = new MySqlConnection("..."))
using(var sc = new MySqlCommand("select * from users", sq))
using(var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sc))
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds); 
    // you don't need to open/close the connection with a datadapter
} // but even without a dataadapter the using would have been closed the connection here
```

Comment: 1+ for the use of `using` statements

Answer (score 0):

as the error said, you aren't closing every connection you open.

Probably because of and exception you get. you can use Tim's suggest:

```
using(var sq = new MySqlConnection("..."))
using(var sc = new MySqlCommand("select * from users", sq))
using(var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sc))
```

or you can use try catch statement:

```
try
{
// Your code here
}
catch
{
    // Whatever code you want here
}
finally
{
    da.Close();
    sc.Close();
    sq.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`new MySqlCommand("select * from users", sq)`

> This implementation of the MySqlDataAdapter opens and closes a
>   MySqlConnection if it is not already open. This can be useful in a an
>   application that must call the DbDataAdapter.Fill method for two or
>   more MySqlDataAdapter objects. If the MySqlConnection is already open,
>   you must explicitly call MySqlConnection.Close or
>   MySqlConnection.Dispose to close it.

so, no need to open the connection, `MySqlDataAdapter` will open it when needed.

better to use **using statements** as other answers.